# Vue-cli in [eslint] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type') error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I installed Vue cli. I'm running the `npm run serve` command without writing any code yet, but unfortunately I'm getting below error. Is there anyone who can help?

The latest version of Node Js is installed. I thought it had something to do with Nodejs so I reinstalled nodejs but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of text, if you can copy it as plain text into the question. Images are not searchable.

Comment: I will be more careful from now on. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue today. Apparently it is caused by the newest version of esquery (1.4.1).
To fix this simply use an older version of esquery. You can do this via:

```
npm install --save-dev esquery@1.4.0
```

Be sure to not update or remove the ^ from "esquery": "^1.4.0" in package.json afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It's an `esquery` bug. Here is the relevant issue:  https://github.com/estools/esquery/issues/135

If you are using yarn you can resolve a previous version of the problematic package (`esquery`) by putting this into `packge.json`. This will ignore the problematic version from one of the deps and use this explicit version.

```json
"resolutions": {
    "esquery": "1.4.0"
},
```

If you are using npm you can replace `resolutions` with `overrides`: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

How resolution works: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/#toc-how-to-use-it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. After I asked my question here, I reinstalled the vue cli project, but this time I did it by installing the default settings. I had installed it using airnb settings in the previous installation. This is how I solved the problem.